# I'm new to GA4. Is there any best way for fetching data from GA4?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

This is how I fetched the data from google analytics 4 using the nodejs client library '@google-analytics/data'.
Is there any other ways for fetching the GA4 data like usersByGender, UsersGeoMap(users from particular country who view my website), usersbybrowser and many more.
Need help!

```
const catchAsync = require("../utils/catchAsync");
const {BetaAnalyticsDataClient} = require("@google-analytics/data");

const propertyId = process.env.PROPERTY_ID;

const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(); 

const fetchDeviceCategories = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
            property: `properties/${propertyId}`, 
            dateRanges: [
                {
                    startDate: '2023-10-31', 
                    endDate: 'today',
                }
            ], 
            dimensions: [
                {
                    name: 'deviceCategory',
                }
            ],
            metrics: [
                {
                    name: 'totalUsers'
                }
            ]
        })
        let transformedDeviceCategoriesData = response?.rows.map(row => ({
            deviceCategory: row.dimensionValues[0].value, 
            value: row.metricValues[0].value,
        }))
        return transformedDeviceCategoriesData || [];
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error, "error from fetching GA4 device categories data");
        next(error); 
    }
};

const fetchUsersByCountry = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
            property: `properties/${propertyId}`, 
            dateRanges: [
                {
                    startDate: '2023-10-31', 
                    endDate: 'today'
                }
            ], 
            dimensions: [
                {
                    name: 'country'
                }
            ],
            metrics: [
                {
                    name: 'totalUsers'
                }
            ]
        })
        const usersByCountry = response?.rows.map(row => ({
            country: row.dimensionValues[0].value, 
            users: row.metricValues[0].value,
        }))
        return usersByCountry || [];
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error, "error from fetching GA4 usersByCountry data");
        next(error); 
    }
};
```

Comment: you are using the correct library.  What data you extract is up to you Check the dimensions and metrics reference to see which ones you can  use.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I have to fetch users by country and show it on my own website dashboard. what should I used to visualize the data? is google charts the best option?

Comment: Yes if you want to display it I often use Google charts for displaying Analytics data from the API.    [Can an AI get Google Analytics reports! YES](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjlvNTxt6oY&t=322s)  Its App script but you can see how it shows analytics data using Google charts and graph